# Creating a listview adapter from a db query

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, android-listfragment, listadapter

I am working on an app and stuck, I am quering a db and get as a return value a hashmap with image path as a key and his name as a value, I want to process those two s.t the image will appear next to its value in a fragment list view but cant understand how to do that.. (android newbie... =) any help?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your data, you would need to bind it to a ListView. To bind data to a ListView, you need to create a ListView Adapter. Take a look at this link by Romain Guy on ListViews: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70. It pretty much goes through the basics of ListView and Adapters.

Comment: Tnx alot I will watch it (i'd rather see a code exmaple or a written tutorial though... =| ) hopefully that gonna help